# Adding addChildViewController hangs the app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I am new in iOS.

I have a view controller in which I have added child view controller using addChildViewController in Parent Controller and it hangs the app.

addChildViewController has 2 webservice calling in the viewDidAppear method. It works fine when webservice calling complete. I want to know how to stop the app hangs problem when adding child view controller.

Below is the code how we add the child view controller:

```
 self.stickerController = StickersViewController()
 self.addChildViewController(self.stickerController)
 self.addSubview(subView: self.stickerController.view, toView: self.view)
 self.stickerController.view.isHidden = true
 self.stickerController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

StickersViewController view controller:

```
import Foundation
class StickersViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource,UISearchBarDelegate {
    var yValue:CGFloat = 65
    var navheight:CGFloat = 65
    var searchView = UIView()
    var searchField = UISearchBar()

    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
    var tableView: UICollectionView!
    var dataDictionary: NSMutableArray!
    var imageCache = [String:UIImage]()
    var titleHeight:CGFloat = 260
    var pagenumber: String = "1"
    var showAnimator: Bool = true
    var isgetLastInsertId: Bool = false
    var isRequestSend: Bool = false
    var stopPagging : Bool = false
    var callFromPagging: Bool = false
    var noDataLabel = UILabel()
    var tryAgainButton = UIButton()

    var gallery_id:Int = 0
    let cellReuseIdentifierEmoji = "cell"
    var tableViewEmoji: UICollectionView!
    var dataDictionaryEmoji: NSMutableArray!
    var pagenumberEmoji: String = "1"
    var isRequestSendEmoji: Bool = false
    var stopPaggingEmoji : Bool = false
    var noDataLabelEmoji = UILabel()
    var callFromPaggingEmoji:Bool = false

    var emojisCategory:UIScrollView!
    var sepratorView:UIView!

    var plusEmojiBtn = UILabel()
    var userEmojiData:NSMutableArray!

    var tabMenuHeight:CGFloat = 40
    var isSearchBarHidden:Bool = false
    var searchBarHeight:CGFloat = 40
    var viewHeight:CGFloat = 0
    var categoryTabMenuHeight:CGFloat = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if isSearchBarHidden == true{
            yValue = 0
        }else{
            searchBarHeight = 80
        }
        if isSearchBarHidden == false{
            viewHeight = self.view.frame.height
        }
        self.view.addSubview(searchView)
        makeSearchView()
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        self.tableView =  UICollectionView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: yValue , width: appWidth,height: viewHeight - yValue - searchBarHeight), collectionViewLayout: layout)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(EmoticonsCategoryTableViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
        tableView.backgroundColor = appBackgroundColor
        self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        self.tableView.alpha = 1
        self.tableView.tag = 1
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)

        //emoji table
        let layoutEmoji: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layoutEmoji.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        layoutEmoji.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)

        self.tableViewEmoji =  UICollectionView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: yValue , width: appWidth,height: viewHeight - yValue - tabMenuHeight - searchBarHeight - categoryTabMenuHeight), collectionViewLayout: layoutEmoji)
        self.tableViewEmoji.tag = 2
        tableViewEmoji.delegate = self
        tableViewEmoji.dataSource = self
        tableViewEmoji.register(ContentFeelingTableViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
        tableViewEmoji.backgroundColor = appBackgroundColor
        self.tableViewEmoji.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        tableViewEmoji.alpha = 0
        self.view.addSubview(tableViewEmoji)
        showAnimator = true;
        paramsPost.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

        emojisCategory = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: viewHeight - searchBarHeight, width: appWidth - 40, height: 40))
        view.addSubview(emojisCategory)

        emojisCategory.backgroundColor = appBackgroundColor
        sepratorView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: emojisCategory.frame.origin.y, width: appWidth , height: 1/divideSepratorScaleValue))
        sepratorView.backgroundColor = appSepratorColor
        view.addSubview(sepratorView)

        plusEmojiBtn.frame = CGRect(x: emojisCategory.frame.width, y: emojisCategory.frame.origin.y + 1/divideSepratorScaleValue, width: 40, height: 40)
        plusEmojiBtn.backgroundColor = appforgroundcolor
        plusEmojiBtn.textColor = navigationColor
        plusEmojiBtn.font = UIFont(name: fontIcon, size: fontSizeHuge)
        plusEmojiBtn.text = "\u{f067}"
        plusEmojiBtn.textAlignment = .center
        view.addSubview(plusEmojiBtn)
        plusEmojiBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tabbedPlus = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.plusTabbed))
        plusEmojiBtn.addGestureRecognizer(tabbedPlus)
    }
    @objc func plusTabbed()  {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "EmojiStoreButtonClicked"), object: nil)
        let pVc = EmojiStickerStore()
        pVc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: pVc)
        self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func getData(){
        let width = appWidth
        let height = appHeight
        if(showAnimator == true){
            //show activity indicator
            if(callFromPagging == false){
                animator.center = self.tableView.center
            }else{
                animator.center = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: (height - CGFloat(activityIndicatorBottomHeight)))
            }
            animator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            animator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
            animator.startAnimating()
            self.view.addSubview(animator)
        }
        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
            isRequestSend = true
            noDataLabel.isHidden = true
            tryAgainButton.isHidden = true
            let imageData = Data()
            paramsPost.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            //remove previous stored data
            if !(searchField.text?.isEmpty)!{
                paramsPost["search"] = searchField.text!
            }

            sendRequest(paramsPost as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, url: "stickers/stickers/limit/"+limitCount+"/page/"+pagenumber, method: "POST",image:imageData) { (succeeded) -> () in
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    if(self.pagenumber == "1" && self.dataDictionary != nil){
                        //remove all stored data from global variable
                        self.dataDictionary.removeAllObjects()
                    }
                    animator.stopAnimating()
                    if  self.isgetLastInsertId == true
                    {
                        //stop refresh spinner
                        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                    }

                    if(succeeded["error_message"] != nil){
                        if let code = succeeded["error_message"] as? String{
                            if !code.isEmpty{
                                openMaintainanceMode(view: self,code: code)
                                return
                            }
                        }
                        //alert error
                        self.view.makeToast(succeeded["error_message"]! as! String, duration: 5, position: .bottom)
                    }else{
                        //success
                        if let responseResult = succeeded["result"] as? NSDictionary{
                            //pagging data
                           // self.pagenumber = "\(responseResult["next_page"]!)"

                            //if(responseResult["total_page"] as! Int == responseResult["current_page"] /as! Int){
                             //   self.stopPagging = true
                            //}else{
                              //  self.stopPagging = false
                           // }



                            self.stopPagging = true
                            if(self.dataDictionary != nil && self.dataDictionary.count > 0){
                                for data in responseResult["emotions"] as! NSMutableArray {
                                    self.dataDictionary.add(data as AnyObject)
                                }
                            }else{
                                // store in global variable
                                if(responseResult["emotions"] != nil){
                                    self.dataDictionary = responseResult["emotions"] as! NSMutableArray
                                    self.noDataLabel.isHidden = true
                                    self.tryAgainButton.isHidden = true
                                    //reload table view
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                    if self.dataDictionary == nil || self.dataDictionary.count == 0{
                        self.noData()
                    }
                    //reinitialize default variables
                    self.isRequestSend = false
                    self.isgetLastInsertId = false
                    self.callFromPagging = false
                })
            }
        }else{
            self.view.makeToast(String(format: NSLocalizedString("No Internet Connection", comment: "")), duration: 5, position: .bottom)
        }
    }
    func makeScrollEmojiContent()  {
        for i in 0..<userEmojiData.count{
            if let dic = userEmojiData[i] as? NSDictionary{
                let title = dic["title"] as! String
                let id = dic["gallery_id"] as! Int
                let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(i*40), y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
                label.tag = id
                if title == "search"{
                    label.font = UIFont(name: fontIcon, size: fontSizeHuge)
                    label.text = "\u{f002}"
                    label.textColor = navigationColor
                    label.backgroundColor =  titleLightColor
                }else{
                    let icon = dic["icon"] as! String
                    let attachment: NSTextAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
                    if let img = self.imageCache[icon]{
                        attachment.image = img
                    }else{
                        if let url = NSURL(string: icon) {
                            if let data = NSData.init(contentsOf: url as URL) {
                                let imageI = UIImage(data: data as Data)!
                                attachment.image = imageI
                                self.imageCache[icon] = imageI
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: -3, width: fontSizeHuge, height: fontSizeHuge)
                    let attachmentString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
                    label.attributedText = attachmentString
                }
                label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                let tabbedPlus = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.labelTabbed(_:)))
                label.addGestureRecognizer(tabbedPlus)
                label.textAlignment = .center
                emojisCategory.addSubview(label)
            }
        }
        if userEmojiData != nil{
            emojisCategory.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(userEmojiData.count * 40), height: emojisCategory.frame.height)
        }
    }
    @objc func labelTabbed(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)  {
        let viewS = sender.view as! UILabel
        let tag = viewS.tag

        for obj in emojisCategory.subviews{
            if obj.tag != tag{
                obj.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            }else{
                obj.backgroundColor = titleLightColor
            }
        }
        self.searchField.text = ""
        if tag == 0{
            self.tableView.alpha = 1
            self.searchView.alpha = 1
            self.tableViewEmoji.alpha = 0
            self.tableViewEmoji.frame.origin.y = yValue
            self.noDataLabelEmoji.isHidden = true
            self.tableViewEmoji.frame.size.height = viewHeight - yValue - tabMenuHeight - searchBarHeight
        }else{
            self.tableView.alpha = 0
            self.searchView.alpha = 0
            gallery_id = tag
            self.tableViewEmoji.frame.origin.y = navheight
            self.tableViewEmoji.frame.size.height = viewHeight - yValue - tabMenuHeight - categoryTabMenuHeight
            if dataDictionaryEmoji != nil && dataDictionaryEmoji.count > 0{
                dataDictionaryEmoji.removeAllObjects()
            }
            tableViewEmoji.reloadData()
            getEmojiFeelingData()
        }
    }
    func getEmojiFeelingData(){
        self.tableView.alpha = 0
        self.tableViewEmoji.alpha = 1
        let width = appWidth
        let height = appHeight
        if(showAnimator == true){
            //show activity indicator
            if(callFromPagging == false){
                animator.center = self.view.center
            }else{
                animator.center = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: (height - CGFloat(activityIndicatorBottomHeight)))
            }
            animator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            animator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
            animator.startAnimating()
            self.view.addSubview(animator)
        }
        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
            isRequestSendEmoji = true
            let imageData = Data()
            paramsPost.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            //remove previous stored data
            if !(searchField.text?.isEmpty)!{
                paramsPost["search"] = searchField.text!
            }
            paramsPost["gallery_id"] = "\(self.gallery_id)"
            sendRequest(paramsPost as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, url: "stickers/emoji-content/", method: "POST",image:imageData) { (succeeded) -> () in
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    if(self.pagenumberEmoji == "1" && self.dataDictionaryEmoji != nil){
                        //remove all stored data from global variable
                        self.dataDictionaryEmoji.removeAllObjects()
                    }
                    animator.stopAnimating()

                    if(succeeded["error_message"] != nil){
                        if let code = succeeded["error_message"] as? String{
                            if !code.isEmpty{
                                openMaintainanceMode(view: self,code: code)
                                return
                            }
                        }
                        //alert error
                        self.view.makeToast(succeeded["error_message"]! as! String, duration: 5, position: .bottom)
                    }else{
                        //success
                        if let responseResult = succeeded["result"] as? NSDictionary{

                            self.stopPaggingEmoji = true
                            if(self.dataDictionaryEmoji != nil && self.dataDictionaryEmoji.count > 0){
                                for data in responseResult["emotions"] as! NSMutableArray {
                                    self.dataDictionaryEmoji.add(data as AnyObject)
                                }
                            }else{
                                // store in global variable
                                if(responseResult["emotions"] != nil){
                                    self.dataDictionaryEmoji = responseResult["emotions"] as! NSMutableArray
                                    self.noDataLabelEmoji.isHidden = true
                                    //reload table view
                                    self.tableViewEmoji.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        self.tableViewEmoji.reloadData()
                    }
                    if self.dataDictionaryEmoji == nil || self.dataDictionaryEmoji.count == 0{
                        self.noDataEmoji()
                    }
                    //reinitialize default variables
                    self.isRequestSendEmoji = false
                    self.callFromPaggingEmoji = false
                })
            }
        }else{
            self.view.makeToast(String(format: NSLocalizedString("No Internet Connection", comment: "")), duration: 5, position: .bottom)
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ sender:UIScrollView) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    func noDataEmoji() {
        self.noDataLabelEmoji = UILabel(frame: CGRect( x: 0, y: 0, width: appWidth, height: 30))
        self.noDataLabelEmoji.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSizeLarge)
        self.view.backgroundColor = appBackgroundColor
        self.noDataLabelEmoji.textFontColor()
        self.noDataLabelEmoji.textAlignment = .center
        self.noDataLabelEmoji.text = NSLocalizedString("No stickers to show.",  comment: "")
        self.noDataLabelEmoji.center = self.tableViewEmoji.center
        self.view.addSubview(self.noDataLabelEmoji)
    }
    func noData() {
        self.noDataLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect( x: 0, y: 0, width: appWidth, height: 30))
        self.noDataLabel.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSizeLarge)
        self.view.backgroundColor = appBackgroundColor
        self.noDataLabel.textAlignment = .center
        self.noDataLabel.textColor = noDataLabelTextColor
        self.noDataLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("No category found with the given search.",  comment: "")
        self.noDataLabel.center = self.tableView.center
        self.view.addSubview(self.noDataLabel)
    }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView.tag == 2{
            if(dataDictionaryEmoji != nil){
                return dataDictionaryEmoji.count
            }else{
                return 0
            }
        }else{
            if(dataDictionary != nil){
                return dataDictionary.count
            }else{
                return 0
            }
        }
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        var width = appWidth - 20
        if collectionView.tag == 1{
            if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad)
            {
                // Ipad
                width = (width - 5*2)/3
            }
            else
            {
                width = (width - 5*1)/2
            }
            return CGSize(width: width, height: 40)
        }else{
            if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad)
            {
                // Ipad
                width = (width - 5*6)/6
            }
            else
            {
                width = (width - 5*4)/4
            }
            return CGSize(width: width, height: 60)
        }

    }

    func makeSearchView() {
        searchView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yValue, width: appWidth, height: 50)
        yValue = yValue + 50
        searchField.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: appWidth, height: 50)
        searchField.delegate = self
        searchField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Search stickers",  comment: "")
        searchView.addSubview(searchField)

        //change search text field attributes
        for mainView in searchField.subviews  {
            for subView in mainView.subviews  {
                if let textField = subView as? UITextField {
                    textField.textColor = searchBarTextColor
                    textField.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSizeMedium)
                }
            }
        }

    }


    func userEmojis() {
        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
            let imageData = Data()
            paramsPost.removeAll()
            paramsPost["user_emojis"] = "1"
            sendRequest(paramsPost as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, url: "stickers/stickers/", method: "POST",image:imageData) { (succeeded) -> () in
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                    if(succeeded["error_message"] != nil){
                        if let code = succeeded["error_message"] as? String{
                            if !code.isEmpty{
                                openMaintainanceMode(view: self,code: code)
                                return
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        for obj in self.emojisCategory.subviews{
                            obj.removeFromSuperview()
                        }
                        //success
                        if let responseResult = succeeded["result"] as? NSDictionary{
                            if let userEmoji = responseResult["useremotions"] as? NSMutableArray{
                                self.emojisCategory.isHidden = false
                                self.sepratorView.isHidden = false
                                self.userEmojiData = userEmoji
                                self.makeScrollEmojiContent()
                            }else{
                                self.emojisCategory.isHidden = true
                                self.sepratorView.isHidden = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            self.getData()            
            self.userEmojis()
    }

    func changeTableViewSize() {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "emojiSearchButtonTabbed"), object: nil)
    }


}
```

Comment: Share the code of the `StickersViewController`. It seems you are making the API calls on the main thread which halts the UI.

Comment: @Adeel: Thanks for the reply. I am calling it in override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {} function.

Comment: The problem is not in the code that you have shared. I asked you to share the code of `StickersViewController` where you are calling the web service(s).

Comment: I have added the code. Please check

Comment: @Adeel: can you please help and tell whats wrong in the code.Thanks

Comment: Where is the `sendRequest` method? I can't see it in the code.

Comment: Can be closed under the official close reason: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_. The supplied code needs to be cut down to an [mcve]. Always debug before pasting code here.